# Vim: Running project from _not_ root file?

Tags: vim

If I am in the root file `main.py` of my project, I can execute it by pressing F9 because of a line roughly like

```
map <buffer> <F9> :w<CR>:exec "!python3 " . %<CR>
```

in my .vimrc.

However, the project is split over multiple files, and I don't want to `:b1` every time just to run it.

I tried the following.
From within a different file

```
let b:pyProjectRoot=main.py
```

and then something like changing the line in my .vimrc to

```
map <buffer> <F9> :w<CR>:exec "!python3 " . b:pyProjectRoot<CR>
```

But for some reason, vim does not recognize the buffer-local variable `b:pyProjectRoot`.

Why is that and how do I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let b:pyProjectRoot=main.py
```

means "assign the value of member `py` of dictionary `main` to the buffer variable `pyProjectRoot`".

The proper form would be:

```
let b:pyProjectRoot = "main.py"
```

which means "assign the string `main.py` to the buffer variable `pyProjectRoot`".

Alternatively, you can define an environment variable:

```
let $PY_PROJECT_ROOT
```

and use it without concatenation:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :w\|!python3 $PY_PROJECT_ROOT<CR>
```

But you should consider using `make` (and `:help :make`) or something similar.

Comment: My original question was not correct, I did put quotes as you said. When I wanted to edit the question to correct that and add more details, I tried numerous things in vim to really get a grasp on what happened, but for some reason it magically worked (without me changing a single line...). But thank you, have an upvote :)